# Why don't we have "rubyonrails.stackoverflow.com"?

Tags: discussion, feedback

Ruby on rails has an important number of questions on stackoverflow.com... And I think Rubyonrails has a very active community on this site.

Why don't we have a subdomain for rubyonrails ? (rubyonrails.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: What's the requirement for it. Just tag the question with [ruby-on-rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Where do you stop with this? [ruby-on-rails] is the 18th most popular tag on the site. Do we create subsites for the 17 above it, as well? How far down the list do we go?

Comment: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 5):

What would a subdomain solve that isn't already provided by the tag [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails)? I don't think that programmers would be confused about the existence of other programming lanuages and frameworks on Stack Overflow, so I see no need for a subdomain.

The Facebook subsite was an experiment, and I haven't heard any positive comments about it. So I strongly doubt that SE will add any more subsites to SE.

Comment: The experiment went south because it was FB, not necessarily because it was a bad idea. Stack Overflow is so flooded with C#/Java/PHP, that on "smaller", but dedicated tags it is easier to promote "their site" as X.stackoverflow.com than X tag on stackoverflow.com. I know several people who can't find their way through the tags. You and I might think they're the best thing since sliced bread, but the truth is that people don't often realize that they can "launch SO" from the tag page  instead of the home page or they can sort/filter by tag, etc.

Comment: Note that I'm not saying that SE should launch subdomains on SO for the less popular tags... just that I can understand the fascination with it and agree that it makes sens from the requester's PoV.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the way it's going now? Why do you need an extra site? SE only accepts new site proposals that don't significantly overlap the scope of an existing site, with very few exceptions (most notably [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)).

[There was a proposal for Ruby on Rails, but it was closed as a duplicate of StackOverflow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/48897/ruby-on-rails)

---

If you're talking about something like http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/, that was due to a tieup with Facebook (or something like that). And I don't see how it helps. Tag favoriting and all already get the job done efficiently, IIRC the facebook.SO site isn't used by many.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: facebook.so? facebook.so is just a tag-filtered version of the main SO. It's not a separate site, just a redirect-y thing. And that's due to a partnership.